# jquery .html result

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm making an ajax call to a server page and print the result in a div via the html method:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
     $.ajax
     ({
    async:false, 
    type: 'GET', cache: false,
    url: '..urlhere..',
        success: function(data){printresult(data);}
      });
});
```

with printresult(data):

```
$("thediv").html(data);
```

This all works but the result itself contains spans with classes. These spans should throw a simple alert when they're hovered. I've implemented that too in document.ready with:

```
$(".spanclass").hover(function () 
{
    alert('j');
});
```

This doesn't work.. Is it because the result comes from ajax and the DOM doesn't see it as a spanclass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `delegate`

```
$('thediv').delegate('hover', '.spanclass', function() { ... });
```

This is its description from jQuery

```
Attach a handler to one or more events for all elements that match the selector, now or in the future, based on a specific set of root elements.
```

Answer (score 2):

You should *delegate* the event, you can use `on` method.

```
$(document).on({
   mouseenter: function(){
    alert('entered')
   }, 
   mouseleave: function(){
    alert('left')
  }     
}, ".spanclass")
```

Answer (score 1):

Set up a `delegate` like this for dynamically added elements

```
$(function(){
   // on document ready setup the delegate for the hover event
   $(document).on('hover', '.spanclass', function(){
       alert('j');
   }); 
});
```

Comment: when do I have to add it? in the onsuccess of my ajax call?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.spanclass').live('mouseover', function() {
    alert('j');
});
```

Comment: @ClydeLobo Using `hover` as an event for `on` method is deprecated too.

Comment: I don't see it as deprecated if I click the link

Comment: *"As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated."*

Comment: didn't see that ^^ expected it to be bigger and more in my face, thanks